# UiTableview values not getting update upon the array value changed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am fetching data from a web service which returns an array and I am displaying that array in the table view. I am facing the issue that table values are getting updated but after some time as first it is showing the old value and upon scrolling it shows the new value.

Below is my code.

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:8.0];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSMutableDictionary *ResultdicNew = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)responseObject];

    NSString *message=[ResultdicNew objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSString *message1=@"";
    if([message isEqualToString:@"success"])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *datadic=[ResultdicNew objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSMutableDictionary *listDataDic=[datadic objectForKey:@"competitors"];
        affArray=[listDataDic valueForKey:@"affiliation"];
        countArray=[listDataDic valueForKey:@"total_count"];
        _lblEventTitle.text=[datadic valueForKey:@"group_name"];

        NSLog(@"affArray here is %@",affArray);
        NSLog(@"countArray.count here is %ld",countArray.count);

        [self revealCompetitorsView];
    }
    else
    {
        message1=[Resultdic objectForKey:@"data"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:message1
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    // NSLog(@"JSON Here is :%lu",(unsigned long)Resultdic.count);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Data"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];

[operation start];



#pragma mark - UITableView Datasource, Delegate Methods
#pragma mark -

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [countArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"menuCellNew";

    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RAMenuCellNew" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        // [cell SetData:[m_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:420];
        UILabel *lbl1=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:421];

        lbl.text=[affArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lbl1.text=[countArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [self.sideTable reloadData];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: you are not reloading the tableview. you will need to reload it.

Comment: Do not reload the table view inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`! But do reload it (or at least the changed rows) each time new data comes in.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i have reloaded the table in the [self revealCompetitorsView];

Comment: @matt i have added this as i was checking it might fix the issue:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - you are not updating the cell when you are given an existing cell for reuse.

You need to move the updating of the cell fields outside of the `if (cell==nil)...` block -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"menuCellNew";

    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RAMenuCellNew" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   }
// [cell SetData:[m_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:420];
   UILabel *lbl1=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:421];

   lbl.text=[affArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   lbl1.text=[countArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   return cell;

}
```

Also, you can register your nib file for your cell in `viewDidLoad` and then you can use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:forIndexPath` which will automatically allocate a new cell if required and you can skip the whole `if (cell==nil...` bit.

You should also consider creating a UITableViewCell subclass and then you can assign your text fields to IBOutlet properties instead of searching by tag.

Comment: thank you ;as i didn't notice that i was not reusing it i did notice that as from more than 380 record my array table is showing only 12 records repeatedly  :) @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code on **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

      UITableViewCell *cell;
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"menuCellNew";

    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RAMenuCellNew" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
        // [cell SetData:[m_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:420];
        UILabel *lbl1=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:421];
        lbl.text=[affArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lbl1.text=[countArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           return cell;
        }
```